# Bootstrap push and pull options does not seems to work

Tags: javascript, css, grid, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use the grid option pull and push, but they do not seems to work. I think it come from my integration of bootstrap css and or js (not sure if push/pull are done via js or CSS).

I have added a push pull that should work at the very top of my web page :

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">Should be on the right</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">Should be on the left</div>
</div>
```

at this URL : 
http://www.dylog.test.resamarket.com/clients/connexion

I have no idea why it does not work, and i am not sure where to start to investigate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The push/pull classes are being applied incorrectly.

The format is:

`[push|pull]-[viewport size]-[column count]`.

I've highlighted one of the columns so you can see the swap more easily.

```css
.col-md-9.push-md-3 {
  background-color: #fc0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9 push-md-3">.col-md-9 .push-md-3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 pull-md-9">.col-md-3 .pull-md-9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the theme is use was sold with bootstrap 4.0.0 alpha 2 and it seems the bootstrap 4 I use is more recent. Syntax has changed.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using a downloaded version of bootstrap 4.0 alpha. If I add the line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

after the `<title>` tag and above your call, it works just fine. Not sure why it does that as the file seems fine. I suggest trying with a production version of Bootstrap.

[col swap http://webdevpdx.com/soverflow/col-swap.png](http://webdevpdx.com/soverflow/col-swap.png)

Comment: Are you sure the columns are swapping like push and pull are supposed to do?

Comment: I am using a paying theme that was sold with bootstrap 4 alpha 2. On top of that my framework put all my js in one huge file (bootstrap, carousel,jquery, tether, owl ...)